# Service modification to per-session

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, architecture

I have a system wherein the already set up service for a specific process used to have a dingle **instance mode**. The service was used to run a long process that could be serve only one client. The architecture is as follows:

[image]

---

Now I am trying to make this wcf service per-session, so that it can run the long operation for two or more clients simultaneously. Since the process usually takes time. I am also sending the percentage of completion back to the client using a callback channel. This is what the architecture looks like the one shown below:

[image]

---

The major difference between the two architecture is:

1. Previously only one user could run the process for multiple
   objects.Now each user can run the long process but for different
   objects.
2. We have added callback facility to the new architecture
   with per-session service.
3. We also plan on giving the user facility
   to terminate the process,if he wishes to or the client connection is
   closed.

   But while trying to achieve the above we are facing the following issues.

   1. The long time taking operation, occurs in database with the help of multiple stored procedures, called one by one from the **static** datamanager class.
   2. Each SP is responsible for addition of around 500k rows in the multiple tables.
   3. Though terminating the connection from client removes the instance of the service but since the database operations are done in the static class, the control gets stuck there and everything stops responding.
   4. I know there is a DBCommand.Cancel() method which stops the operation associated with the DBCommand, but since the class is static cancelling that is also not possible.

---

Please suggest the architectural changes needed to solve this issue. I am ready to share more details.

Comment: Do you really need to make the DataManager a static class ? Wouldn' be better if every client had its own instance of DataManager with its own DbCommand you could cancel ?

Comment: Yeah I agree, the architecture is part of a very big and old system. Since the services were previously single instance services a static class was an okay option. But with the change of this service, the static class poses a problem. I just want the best way to architecturally handle the situation.

Comment: From what I understand, you want multiple client at the same time and the  static behavior that makes to have a singleton don't match together. I would correct that. But maybe I don't understand everything

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I need, if there is no way to make it work with the static since refactoring it would be troublesome.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation and diagram

Comment: I just make my comment into an answer so your question has an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want multiple client at the same time and the `static` behavior that makes to have a `singleton` don't match together.

I would correct that.

Regards